# Where is the reset icon?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, material-design

I want to use a reset icon. The closest one I could find is  `Icons.Default.LockReset` after adding `"androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.5.1"`, but there is a lock in the middle.

It isn't available in Android Studio either. Does it have another name?

[image: Android studio]

Other icons that are close are: refresh, replay and restore.

Comment: How is what you want different from the "refresh" or "replay" ones? Just the position of the arrow?

Comment: Looking at [the material icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.query=reset), are you looking for "Restart Alt" perhaps?

Comment: @TylerV Yes. I want the "lock reset" icon without the lock. The restore icon also has something in the middle. I am just surprised there is no reset icon, I could have sworn it was there before (2 years ago when I was using Java and Xml). It makes wander if we are not supposed to use it.

Comment: @CommonsWare It looks good. The google clock app uses it, so I will go with it. Not sure why it's called alt.

Comment: Yeah, other than the end position of the arrow, "replay" sounds like what you are describing... (arrow in a counter-clockwise circle with nothing in the middle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The google clock app uses `Icons.Default.RestartAlt` to reset a timer.

Answer (score 1):

why not use icons from font awesome, import the sdk and just find the icon you want to use https://fontawesome.com/icons